# Configuring MIME type

Tags: google-app-engine, kml, webapp2

Hi I want to configure my mime type:

The MIME type for KML files is

```
* application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml
```

How can I do this with google app engine? I generate KML on a template that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>{% for article in articles %}{% if article.geopt %}
<Placemark><name></name>
<description>
<![CDATA[{% if article.kmluri2view %}<img src="http://{{host}}/images/{{ article.kmluri2view.key.id }}.jpg">{% endif %}<a href="http://{{host}}/{{article.key.id}}"> {{ article.title }} </a><br/>{{article.text}}]]></description><Point><coordinates>{{article.geopt.lon|floatformat:2}},{{article.geopt.lat|floatformat:2}}</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>{% endif %}{% endfor %}
</Document>
</kml>
```

Updated the code I try set the MIME type like below. How can I verify it works?

```
class KMLHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):            
        start=datetime.datetime.now()-timedelta(days=10)#vary  
        host = os.environ.get("HTTP_HOST", os.environ["SERVER_NAME"])       
        logging.debug('host '+host)                
        count = int(self.request.get('count')) if not self.request.get('count')=='' else 1000

        from google.appengine.api import memcache
        memcache.flush_all()
        memcache_key = "ads"
        data = memcache.get(memcache_key)
        if data is None:
          a= Ad.all().filter("modified >", start).filter("url IN", ['www.koolbusiness.com']).filter("published =", True).order("-modified").fetch(count)
          memcache.set("ads", a)  
        else:
          a = data
        dispatch='templates/kml.html'
        template_values = {'a': a , 'request':self.request, 'host':host}
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), dispatch)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: I run it with pure webapp just dispatching a list with entities to the template. If you suggest a framework you are most welcome to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply set the `Content-Type` header in the response to the mimetype you want. If you're using webapp, for instance, you do it like this:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'
```

Comment: OK thanks I try it like pasted above and I will check how it works