# Google maps doesn't link kml file

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a PHP function that creates a kml file. (I validated the output and it's a valid KML file).

Then, I use Google Maps with these file, but I don't know why, no data appears on the map...

In PHP, I have this:

```
//some stuff here
return 'iniMap("", "", "http://my.web.com/Class/API/GMaps/Rep/'.$g->make($l, $a, $user).'.kml")';
```

This function is called via AJAX, so the return string will be evaluated with JS "eval()". My Google Maps functions are:

```
/*GOOGLE MAPS FUNCTIONS*/
function iniMap(x,y,url){
    n=document.createElement('DIV');
    n.id='map_canvas';
    ge('con').appendChild(n);
    var latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
    var map=new google.maps.Map(ge("map_canvas"),{zoom:6,center:latlng,mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});
    var div1=document.createElement('DIV');
    var homeControl1=new makeControl(div1,'t1');
    var div2=document.createElement('DIV');
    var homeControl2=new makeControl(div2,'t2');
    var div3=document.createElement('DIV');
    var homeControl3=new makeControl(div3,'t3');
    var div4=document.createElement('DIV');
    var homeControl4=new makeControl(div4,'t4');
    var ctaLayer=new google.maps.KmlLayer(url);
    div1.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(div1);
    div2.index = 2;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(div2);
    div3.index = 3;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(div3);
    div4.index = 4;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(div4);
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}

function makeControl(d,t){
    d.style.padding='5px';
    var controlUI=document.createElement('DIV');
    controlUI.style.backgroundColor='#FEFEFE';
    controlUI.style.borderStyle='solid';
    controlUI.style.borderWidth='1px';
    controlUI.style.cursor='pointer';
    controlUI.style.textAlign='center';
    controlUI.style.width='60px';
    controlUI.style.height='17px';
    d.appendChild(controlUI);
    var controlText=document.createElement('DIV');
    controlText.style.fontFamily='Arial,sans-serif';
    controlText.style.fontSize='12px';
    controlText.style.paddingLeft='4px';
    controlText.style.paddingRight='4px';
    controlText.innerHTML=t;
    controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI,'click',function(){doAction(t);});
}

function doAction(t){
    if(t=='t1'){document.location.href='http://my.web.com?t=sy0'}
    else if(t=='t2'){document.location.href='http://my.web.com?t=sm0'}
    else if(t=='t3'){document.location.href='http://my.web.com?t=sw0'}
    else if(t=='t4'){document.location.href='http://my.web.comt=sd0'}
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Is your KML file [hosted on a publicly available webserver](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer)?

Comment: Yes. I mean, I can put "my.web.com/Class/API/GMaps/Rep/name_of_file.kml" and google chrome downloads it...

Comment: my.web.com doesn't look like a publicly available webserver.  The question is can Google download it to their server to render the tiles, not can you download it in your browser.  What happens if you pass the URL to [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com), like [this](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fso_kml.kml&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&t=h&z=16)?

Comment: well, the "my.web.com" is just an example...

Comment: I figured as much, but you didn't answer the question...

Comment: Oh, I missunderstand the message... Well, I tried it and it tells me is not a valid kml file. But by error I puted "my.web.com/Class/API/GMaps/Rep//name_of_file.kml" (with the double slash) and show me a previous kml file I was editing in this morning...

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking anymore.  Can provide a publicly available link to a test KML file (doesn't need to be your real data) that exhibits the problem?  Is your server configuring the [headers for the KML file](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server) correctly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565390/configuring-mime-type

Comment: http://new.gredule.com/Class/API/GMaps/Rep/356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.kml here is the current KML file I'm using by testing. Using "feedvalidator.com" tells is a valid file. My server configuration will be ok (in an earlier version - gredule.com, not new.gredule.com - it works). My problem is the following: when I make the map and I attach the kml file, the map shows as I have no kml file. And I don't know why it's it happening... Then, in google maps the first direction doesn't work, but it does with a double slash at the end... Thanks for all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem...

It was a cache issue. Maybe some a file with bad data was cached, and therefore my function was always getting that bad file...

Today I changed the way to generate the file name, and the map start working...

Thanks to @geocodezip for all the answers and sorry for the time wasting...